# set/get dynamically custom attribute

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dynamic, custom-attributes

Major modern browsers support setting/retrieving custom attribute dynamically, except IE-family. How can I set/get my custom attribute in all browsers?

This is what I've tried so far:

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

JS:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.setAttribute('custom-attr', 'custom-value');
alert(myInput.getAttribute('custom-attr'));
```

or

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
var customAttr = document.createAttribute('custom-attr');
customAttr.value = 'custom-value';
myInput.setAttributeNode(customAttr);
alert(myInput.getAttribute('custom-attr'));
```

In both cases IE `alert()` returns `null`.

Comment: I don't actually see a problem with your first code snipped. Tried it in MSIE 6.0 and 8.0, displays "custom-value" correctly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I tested your code on IE7/8

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.setAttribute('custom-attr', 'custom-value');
alert(myInput.getAttribute('custom-attr'));
```

and it runs fine. Does that simple test case fail for you, or are you actually doing something different?

You can use bracket notation

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput['custom-attr'] = 'custom-value';
alert(myInput['custom-attr']);
```

If you did not have the `-` in the name, you can use dot notation

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.customAttr = 'custom-value';
alert(myInput.customAttr);
```

Comment: Those aren't actually attributes; they're properties.

Comment: A note to help finding additional information on Google: this feature is called "expando properties".

Answer (score 3):

Your code works just fine on IE6, IE7, IE8, FF, Chrome, Opera.